# Whole section is ending up clickable

Tags: html, css

I am having a strange problem but cannot see why. I have a banner in a section of the site but turns out the entire div has become clickable! Can you spot why?

```
<div id="slider" style="height:20%;">
    <h2 style="background:#66c17d">
        <span class="color1">sample text</span>
    </h2>
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/store"> 
        <img class="sample" src="images/slide_sample2.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#slider {
    height:40px;
    background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');
    text-align:center;
}
```

Please correct me!

Comment: I think we'll need to see some more of the code. What styling do you have on the link inside the slider? What scripts (if any) are running? Can you set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: you should add a fiddle for us to know what you are really wanting

Comment: I cannot confirm the behaviour with just the code you've shown, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87zgs/)

Comment: More code needed . Fiddle works just fine...

Comment: ok i hope i have used fork correctly:
http://jsfiddle.net/87zgs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere else in your code, you probably have :

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Add this:

```
#slider a {display:inline-block}
```

Comment: Spot on Mark. Thank you VERY much! Why did that code snippet solve the problem?

Comment: @user2261249 Long story :P basically in CSS, elements are either block-level or inline. Links are naturally inline elements (flow inline with text, don't accept explicit height/width values, etc). You made it behave as a block level element with display:block... block level elements grow to the width of their containers, and have a few other interesting characteristics. Inline-block makes it behave like a block element, but keeps it inline. Sorry, I'm not very good at explaining it. See http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/ http://www.impressivewebs.com/inline-block/